# Gmail SMTP timeout on 587 port, EC2 in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail-api, private-subnet

I have a few ec2 instances running in private subnet, one of them needs to use SMTP  to send emails over 587 port, since the EC2 is in a private subnet I think im getting a timeout over the port, Is there anyway to fix this

Answer (score 0):

---- updated(20min later)

Problem located on our ACL configuration.
added:

port: 587

source: 0.0.0.0/0

To Allows inbound traffic under your public ACL which your NAT used.

---- original

Same problem here. We can use 587 from the public subnet, but private subnet not works.